# what is currently the official version of the Android kernel?

Tags: android, linux-kernel

currently the official version of the kernel is the Android 3.4? because my text book on android 4 shows how the kernel version 2.6?

Answer (score 1):

There are many versions for different devices or product. You can find from [here](https://android.googlesource.com/kernel/common/).